# Disable LOV button in Web PL*SQL (javascript, Oracle, HTML)

Tags: javascript, oracle

I have a frame with a table.  In that table I have some fields including one with a button that opens a LOV form (Oracle List of Values; a form to allow selection to fill the associate text box)

I have to disable/enable the Text box and LOV button according to other fields.  But I am only succeeding in disabling the text box, the LOV button remains enabled.  I am unable to work out how to disable the LOV button.  I beleive it is because it does not have its own ID.

To disable I am doing

```
document.forms[0].P_ACT_ID_ARRAY[rowNumber].disabled = true;
```

The table cell contents (text box and LOV button) are defined with;

```
<TD NOWRAP id="P_ACT_ID_ARRAY" > <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="P_ACT_ID_ARRAY" name="P_ACT_ID_ARRAY"  SIZE="15"  MAXLENGTH="200" value="BOARD_TRAVEL" ; " > <a name="P_ACT_ID_LOV" onClick="ACT_LOV('P_ACT_ID_ARRAY',this,'BP_GEN_MGT_ADMN','0000676');"  href="javascript:void(0)" > <IMG SRC="/v12conf_images/lov.jpg" border=0></a></TD>
```

Any help to disable the LOV button appreciated.

=== after response from gdoron

I modified the HTML to be the follwoing

```
<TD NOWRAP id="P_ACT_ID_ARRAY" > <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="P_ACT_ID_ARRAY" name="P_ACT_ID_ARRAY"  SIZE="15"  MAXLENGTH="200" value="ADMIN" ; " > <a ID="Karl" name="P_ACT_ID_LOV" onClick="ACT_LOV('P_ACT_ID_ARRAY',this,'BP_GEN_MGT_ADMN','0000676');"  href="javascript:void(0)" > <IMG SRC="/v12conf_images/lov.jpg" border=0></a></TD>
```

and added

```
document.getElementById('KARL').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].disabled = "disabled"
```

but got the same result; text box disabled, LOV button still enabled.

===   Further information   ===

I can get it to work on the line above in the table but not the line I'm working on.  I am adding a line and trying to disable the LOV button as I add it (to enable later once other values are present).  Does anyone have any ideas why the newly created row does not work but the pre-existing one does?  I think this may tbe the crux of my problem.

```
 document.getElementById('P_ACT_ID_ARRAY').getElementsByTagName('a')[rowNumber -1 ].disabled = true;
 document.getElementById('P_ACT_ID_ARRAY').getElementsByTagName('img')[rowNUmber -1].style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Regards
Karl

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

your HTML isn't valid you have multiple elements with the same `P_ACT_ID_ARRAY`id.

After you fix it, try this:

```
document.getElementById('P_ACT_ID_ARRAY')
        .getElementsByTagName('img')[0].disabled = "disabled"
```

But it looks like you need to disable the anchor surrounding the image:

```
document.getElementById('P_ACT_ID_ARRAY')
        .getElementsByTagName('a')[0].disabled = "disabled"
```

Comment: That's exactley what I'm currently doing.  It disables the Text box but not the LOV button.  I need to disable the LOV button as well.   ** Actually having just written this I see a difference - let me go try it.  **

Comment: No, same result.  Text box is disabled, LOV button still enabled.